# Newtonsoft date parse error (removes one day)

Tags: javascript, c#, json, typescript

In my TypeScript project, there's a function where the users can select a date.

For example: (JSON)

```
"IssueDate":"Wed Jan 18 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Jordan Standard Time)"
```

However in my controller when parsing the object using Newtonsoft, the result date prop is always less by one day

```
IssueDate: {1/17/2017 10:00:00 PM}
```

Any idea why this is happening? do I need to configure Newtonsoft in a way to prevent this?

Comment: Midnight GMT +2 converted to 10PM GMT when parsing

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Seems that `Kind` property of `DateTime` parser in controller side being set to UTC instead of local time, perhaps you can either display in local time with `ToString` or change the parser behavior to accept local time.

Comment: The way I'm obtaining the object is from using the `[FromBody]` attribute. so how can I set `Kind` to be local time  instead of UTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your register method of webapi project  try this

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling =DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

Comment: setting `DateTimeZoneHandling.Local` did this for me, so update your answer :)